# Definite positive measure and GNS representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.

Let $\mu$ be a positive definite complex measure ([D, p295]): 
we have $\mu(f*f^*)\geq 0$ for any compact support continuons function $f \in C_c(G)$.

In [D, p 297], the author constructs an associated unitary representation of $G$ from scratch.

I would like construct this representation with another method which seems to me more natural:
First to obtain a representation of the involutive algebra $C_c(G)$ by using the GNS construction ([T, p 134]). Then I must check the operators $\pi(f)$ *are bounded*. After this task, I would like *find an extension* of $\pi$ to a non-degenerate representation of the involutive algebra $L^1(G)$ (and deduce a unitary representation of $G$ by [D, p 284]).

> 1) Is it possible?

My problems are the *are bounded* and *find an extension*.

The inequality
$$
\int_G f^**g^**g*f d\mu \leq K_g\int_G f^**f d\mu,\qquad f,g \in C_c(G)
$$
seems to be the key in order to show that the operators of the GNS representation are bounded. But I do not see how I can prove it.

2) Is this inequality true or false?

3) What is the relationship between *-representations of $C_c(G)$ and *-representations of $L^1(G)$?

[D] Dixmier-C*-algebras

[T] Thill-Introduction to Normed *-Algebras and their Representations. 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1558.pdf